# Google Chrome Extension Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read through some of docs, I've searched for sample concepts, and I'm still struggling with coming up with something that works at a dom level. I want my background page to display a menu of sorts that I want to be able to do things with the dom elements on the page. Currently just append a new element based on click.

I am attempting to load jQuery in with my own custom js. I can't tell if it's the way I tried to write the manifest, I can't tell what or where specifically is happening where, and I can't get firebug to report on it either way so I feel like I'm in the dark not knowing how to debug my issue and try to track down what I'm doing wrong.

So I am here hoping someone can show me a very core example of this stuff so I can actually work. Also if anyone knows how I can debug I'd be happy to know that too..

Comment: You really shouldn't put anything except scripts in your `background` page.

Comment: The background page is never viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,

1. You shouldn't put anything except scripts and element related to the scripts itself in [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html), since it should be hidden from users.
2. If you want to load jQuery into any pages of your extension, you can do it like what you would normally in a webpage.
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`
3. For debugging, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open up the *Developer Tools* (on any of your extension's pages), or click "background.html" on the extensions page (chrome://extensions).
4. If you want to have control of the DOM on webpages, you can use [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) for that.
5. For more extension examples, visit http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html (a lot of cool stuffs!)

[image]

> Click the link to open up Developer Tools. (It is like Firebug. And an interesting fact for you, it is developed by Apple, not Google. D:)

Hope this helps you out and answers all your questions!

Comment: er, Google builds on Apple's Web Inspector as Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: @gengkev, they are just the same thing overall ;)

Comment: well, yes, but Chrome [builds on it enough](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) so that I consider it to be different. :)

Comment: Woot! Never knew they have documentations for this!